# Fiji: imglib2 FFT algorithm explanation

Tags: java, image-processing, fft, imagej, prime-factoring

I've already worked with FourierTransform and FFTConvolution classes, I've also studied their codes in order to adapt them to my program, anyway I still have some doubts about those classes and I hope you can help me!

First, dimensions of the output resulting from the FourierTransform and those of the fftKernel in the FFTConvolution class differ from those of the input images, why? Why, for example, if I transform a 256x256 image I get back a 281x560 spectrum?

Secondly, trying to find out an answer to the first doubt I have, I find out that the spectrum dimensions are calculated by using the package edu.mines.jtk.dsp and in particular the classes FftReal/FftComplex, both based on the Pfacc class. Comments to the Pfacc class said that this class implements the PFA algorithm for the FFT computation, so my second doubt is this: do the FourierTransform and FFTConvolution classes implement the PFA algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

For convolution the no of output points is equal to:

```
N_out = N_in + K + 1
```

where:

```
N_out = no of output points
N_in = no of input points
K = kernel size
```

So it looks like you are convolving your 256x256 image with a 304x25 kernel.

As for the PFA algorithm, this is just an implementation detail - the FFT dimension is broken down into powers of small primes. The end result is the same as for a DFT though.

Comment: both the image and the kernel are 256x256

Comment: In that case please include at least the relevant sections of your code in the question.

Comment: the problem isn't in my code, I only wanted to have explanations about the classes FFTConvolution and FourierTransform of the library imglib2, thanks

Comment: "the problem isn't in my code" -- great story bro'. Seriously though, even if you believe there is nothing wrong with your code, it would be helpful for others to see how you're calling these routines, and might help to provide further insight into your problems.

Comment: ahahah I didn't explain well..I'm writing a plugin using imglib2,this plugin must produce the same results as those of a Matlab routine. The code work fine to me, I've already checked it and I've also talked to some of the Fiji developers.Anyway I've noticed some discrepancies in the intermediate results of the two codes, caused by the FFT computation. The FFTs computed in Matlab and the one computed in Fiji differ of about 1e0,while before convolution the difference between the input images was of 1e-7.

Comment: So I checked the code of the Fiji FFTConvolution class and noticed those strange dimensions of the FFT, now I'm trying to find out why from a 256x256 image I got a 281x560 spectrum